# Cognito Signout flow not clearing cookies of ADFS from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I’m currently working on integrating an application using Cognito with external IdPs (ADFS) using SAML. I have done the following steps for my user pool

1)I have created a SAML identity provider by importing the metadata of my ADFS server and enabled the signout flow checkbox.

2)Added the relying party trusts in the ADFS server for my userpool. Configured the singin end point as https://.auth..amazoncognito.com/saml2/idpresponse and logout endpoint as https://.auth..amazoncognito.com/saml2/logout.

3)Imported signing certificate from cognito to the relying party trust signature section.

When I am logging in it is asking for username and password of my Active directory. But During logout the request is going to /saml/logout endpoint and I am getting a successful response. Cognito cookie is getting cleared from the browser. But my ADFS cookies still remains in the browser. Next time When I am logging it my ADFS credentials are getting picked up from the browser. Cognito signout flow is unable to clear the federated IDP's cookies even when sign out flow is enabled. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

although this is not an answer for your question I would like to know how you managed to authenticate users using SAML Idp?

I've setup SAML Idp and enable it in my app client.

I am trying to log in using and android app that has 2 text fields for username and password and a login button.

I get UserNotFoundException. I followed Amazon documentation and cannot find a way to get over it. I'm confused.

Funny thing is that everything works flawlessly when I log in using the auto generated UI by Cognito that is accesses using below format.

[Cognito Auto Generated UI](https://%3Cyour_user_pool_domain%3E/login?response_type=code&client_id=%3Cyour_client_id%3E&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com)

Comment: When you set up federation to some IDP, the IDP login page gets opened where user can provide his details for authenticating himself. If user enters username and password in any other page for example the page you designed with username and password, the idea of federating access is defeated. You have to open the IDP login page in a new window and once authenticated you have to post back the JWT obtained to your page using script like window.opener.postMessage('jwt','domainname'). Hope this helps. cheers.